# Create XML using an .xsd file inC#

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xsd2code

How to create an XML file using an XSD file in C#? I want to write a program that will fetch an XSD file, fill the elements and save it into an XML file.

Answer (score 0):

The [XML Schema](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/) is supposed to describe the Schema of an XML file. In order to create an XML file **according to the specific XSD**, you cannot do it only by using the XSD. You need data too... This cannot be made automatically. You have somehow to add data to your question.

Hope I helped!